# SQL Query to display records in a table for duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contain 3 fields   RecordID, PhoneNumber,Disposition. I am using SQL server.

Case 1:-

```
RecordID     PhoneNumber   Disposition

2345         9212345667    PNP
2345         9212345667    PNP
2345         9212345667    PNP 
4563         8234589012    PNP
```

Here I should display single record from  2 rows.

```
Result : 2345       9212345667    PNP
         4563       8234589012    PNP
```

Only one record should be displayed based on RecordID, PhoneNumber and Disposition duplicates.

Case 2:-

```
RecordID     PhoneNumber   Disposition

2345         9212345667    PNP
2345         9212345667    CBK
4563         8234589012    PNP

Result : 4563      8234589012    PNP
```

Here RecordID and PhoneNumber are same but Dispositions are different for first 2 records. So the records should not be displayed.Third record is no where related to duplicate values of RecordID and PhoneNumber. So it should display.

Thanks Please help.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Maybe a SELECT DISTINCT would to the trick?

Comment: Normalise your design such that duplicates aren't stored in the first place

Answer (score 2):

To get each row just once and omit duplicates use `distinct`

```
select distinct RecordID, PhoneNumber, Disposition from mytable
```

To get rows where duplicates don't exist use `group by / having count(*) = 1`

```
select RecordID, PhoneNumber, Disposition from mytable
group by RecordID, PhoneNumber, Disposition 
having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Sql server has `Top(1) with ties ... order by` plus `row_number()`

```
Select Top(1) with ties RecordID, PhoneNumber, Disposition
from table
-- case 1 
order by row_number() over (partition by RecordID, PhoneNumber, Disposition order by recordID)  
-- case 2 
--order by row_number() over (partition by RecordID, PhoneNumber order by recordID)
;
```